# Atlassian Bamboo behind IIS7 with Isapi redirect

Tags: iis, jetty, isapi, bamboo, isapi-redirect

I'm attempting to use Bamboo behind IIS 7. I have exhausted all of my resources so Im hoping someone here can help. After starting bamboo and trying to connect my browser eventually times out with a 503. Please note that only bamboo currently has a problem. JIRA,Confluence and Crowd all work without issue

**The logs from bamboo state**

```
jvm 1| 2010-02-13 00:02:16.256::WARN:  EXCEPTION  
jvm 1| java.lang.IllegalAccessError  
jvm 1|      at org.mortbay.jetty.ajp.Ajp13Connection.<init>(Ajp13Connection.java:51)  
jvm 1|      at org.mortbay.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector.newHttpConnection(Ajp13SocketConnector.java:79)  
jvm 1|      at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.<init>(SocketConnector.java:182)  
jvm 1|      at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.accept(SocketConnector.java:102)  
jvm 1|      at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:707)  
jvm 1|      at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)  `
```

**and the Isapi_redirect.log states:**

```
[Sat Feb 13 00:07:40.360 2010] [2248:5256] [info] jk_ajp_common.c (1143): (worker4) can't receive the response header message from tomcat, tomcat (127.0.0.1:8035) has forced a connection close for socket 620  
[Sat Feb 13 00:07:40.360 2010] [2248:5256] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (1962): (worker4) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)  
[Sat Feb 13 00:07:40.361 2010] [2248:5256] [info] jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (worker4) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable),  (attempt=1)  
[Sat Feb 13 00:07:40.361 2010] [2248:3860] [info] jk_ajp_common.c (1143): (worker4) can't receive the response header message from tomcat, tomcat (127.0.0.1:8035) has forced a connection close for socket 636  
[Sat Feb 13 00:07:40.361 2010] [2248:3860] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (1962): (worker4) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)  
[Sat Feb 13 00:07:40.361 2010] [2248:3860] [info] jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (worker4) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable),  (attempt=1)  `
```

I have configured Bamboo to use the jetty Configuration file per the instructions here:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Getting+Bamboo+Standalone+to+use+the+jetty.xml+file

**I have configured my jetty.xml and added**

```
<Call name="addConnector">  
   <Arg>  
     <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector">  
       <Set name="port">8035</Set>  
     </New>  
   </Arg>  
</Call>
```

The Isapi config info:

**workers.properties.minimal looks like this:**

```
#jira  
worker.worker1.type=ajp13  
worker.worker1.host=localhost  
worker.worker1.port=8009  

#confluence  
worker.worker2.type=ajp13  
worker.worker2.host=localhost  
worker.worker2.port=8014  

#crowd  
worker.worker3.type=ajp13  
worker.worker3.host=localhost  
worker.worker3.port=8016  

#bamboo  
worker.worker4.type=ajp13  
worker.worker4.host=localhost  
worker.worker4.port=8035
```

**uriworkermap.properties file:**

```
/jira/*=worker1  
/confluence/*=worker2  
/crowd/*=worker3  
/bamboo/*=worker4
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With AJP, i don't think you're supposed to use isapi_rewrite - that's like connecting an HTTP plug to an AJP socket, its not a match.

You want an AJP connector on your IIS side:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Answer (score -1):

check that the version of the jetty ajp jar file matches your version of jetty